# Web2py adding table rows with form elemts

Tags: forms, web2py, helper

Does anyone know of a way to add a form element, specifically a SELECT helper, in a TD of its own, in a table created using the TABLE helper from a 2D list? I want each table row to be created from a row in my list of lists, then to add a SELECT at the end of each table row. I've tried along the lines of:

```
form=FORM(TABLE(TR(*items, SELECT([other items])) for items in list))
```

This is evidently the wrong approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. I appended the new SELECT elements to a list of table elements and referred to the list instead of *items.